# Uninstall git bash from rails?

Tags: ruby, git, bash, uninstallation

How can I uninstall git bash from rainstaller?

It had thrown some errors when it was time to put user and mail in the latest version of rainstaller. I am thinking of preventing it from running when I use Ruby from prompt. I expect a more elegant way than to delete the git directory.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to use ruby for this. You said you put insome errors, have you tried using: `git config --global --unset-all [whatever you messed up]`? It seems like deleting is a bit of an overkill

Comment: I tried all of them, from configuring the environment variables via CMD, in registry, but there is no case, the problem is that my current user has characters like "&", the idea was to avoid creating another user. But it seems that I do not have many alternatives, 
I already had a desktop version of git, which started me throwing errors with the last update of rainstaller, I do not know if the ideal will be to download an old version, to avoid a slaughter like delete the folder .pd: and try what I You landed and did not work

Comment: I have already solved. I created a new user without special characters, and everything is going well!

Comment: creating a new user (with a different environment) is not really *solving* the problem. instead you just go away and don't care about the problem any longer. in any case, if you find the answer to your question yourself, please add it as a proper "Answer" and *accept* it, so the Q doesn't show up as *unanswered* in the searched.